# C++: use of overloaded operators in my namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading

I'm trying to implement scalar product in C++ inside a library:

```
namespace Foo
{
    double operator* (vector<double> left, vector<double> right)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I'm having problems calling it inside the main program. Calling

```
int main (void)
{
    ...
    double result = Foo::operator* (l, r);
    ...
}
```

isn't a good solution, while:

```
int main (void)
{
    ...
    double result = l * r; //l, r are vector<double>
    ...
}
```

isn't working.

[`using namespace Foo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?rq=1) is considered a bad practice for global usage.

What is a good way to call my `operator*` fuction inside `main` scope?

Comment: Overloaded operators are supposed to work via ADL. Write your own vector class in Foo.

Comment: vector * vector is double, this does not make any sense

Comment: @billz It does when you use the dot product

Comment: You can use `use namespace Foo;` inside `main`.

Comment: It's better to have a method called "dot" to be explicit about what it does than to overload * for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to comment too much if you should overload the `*` operator like this. All I'm going to say is that it will confuse a lot of people.

You can bring in just the operator instead of the whole namespace.

```
using Foo::operator*;
double result = l * r;
```

For custom classes you can use [ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), like below:

```
namespace Foo
{
    struct dvector : public vector<double> 
    { };

    double operator*(dvector left, dvector right)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    Foo::dvector l, r;
    double result = l * r;
    return 0;
}
```